# SPARQL property path, 1st part is unique, path repeats after

Tags: sparql

Assume we have the triples

```
a1  blah <http://foo.com/f>
a1  pt   c1
c1  pt   d1
```

How would I construct a SPARQL query to select `a1` or `c1` or `d1`? I need to be able to walk one `blah` predicate or multiple `pt` predicates.

So  a1 can be part of a triple like : `a1 blah <http://foo.com/f>`
but I dont know how to specify the case where its not a1, but its an object connected to a1 through another path in the other direction. But I also need to retain the path using blah, since thats what a1 or f1 is connected to the object by

Here is how I got it to work, but its not pretty:

```
select  * from
{
  # other sparql stuff before it
   { ?s blah <http://foo.com/f>
     ?s pt+  <c1>  }
   UNION
   { <c1> blah <http://foo.com/f>  }
}
```

I can change 'c1' to 'a1' or 'd1' and the above sparql still works

Comment: You need the sequence operator `/` instead of the alternative operator `|`.

Comment: Do you want the *specific* predicates **blah** and **pt**, or do you want any sequence of "this predicate and then repetitions of that predicate"?

Comment: It doesnt have to be a specific predciate. I'm trying get any subject that is connected by either of those predicates. The 'blah' predicate will only connect a subject to a object, but the 'pt' predicate can connect items N connections away.  I will try the sequence operator and let you know.

Comment: @AriesOnTheCusp What you say in the comment makes it sound like you *do* want an alternative, not a sequence.  Your title says "1st part is unique, path repeats after" but your comment says "connected by *either* of those predicates".  Which do you actually want: ("x p y" OR "x q* y") or ("x p z", then "z q* y")?

Comment: @AriesOnTheCusp rereading your example in light of your comment, I think you want a path of the form `p?/q*` which says "zero or one p followed by zero or more q".  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think the issue is in the phase "I need to be able to walk one 'blah' predicate or multiple 'pt' predicates".  Your example doesn't include "one 'blah' predicate", it includes "one 'blah' predicate **and then** multiple 'pt' predicates", as well as "zero 'blah' predicates **and then** multiple 'pt' predicates".  So I think you want "an *optional* blah **and then** zero or more 'pt' predicates".

Comment: I updated the description. Sorry if I am not describing it well. Basically there is a path that connects one of the IRIs to http://foo.com/f   but I dont know how to connect a path from multiple directions

Comment: Thank you for updating.  What do you mean by " but its an object connected to a1 through another path in the other direction."  All the examples show **object "blah or multiple pts" f1**.  I'm not clear what you mean "the other direction".

Comment: Because the path "a1  blah <http://foo.com/f>" is one direction, and then the path "a1  pt   c1" is another path direction, but I have to hang everything off of " blah <http://foo.com/f>"

Comment: I got it to work Joshua, let me know what you think

Comment: @Aries the right hand side of your union doesn't introduce any bindings.  All the results you're getting are from the left hand side.  And the left hand side says that s has to be connected to find by blah **and** connected to c1 by a chain of pt. That doesn't *sound* like what you were asking for in the question...

Comment: But I guess,  if c1 is the thing you were looking for,  then it sounds like you're trying to ask for x such that "x is directly connected to f by blah,  or x is connected by a *reverse* chain of pt to something that is connected directly to f by blah." If that's right,  you just want `?x (^pt)+/blah <f>`. No need for a union or for the intermediate variable ?s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AKSW's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213419/sparql-property-path-1st-part-is-unique-path-repeats-after#comment60061339_36213419) was exactly right, you need to use a sequence, not an alternative.  Based on your example, it sounds like you actually want subjects that are connected to a specific object by a chain of zero or one occurrences of "blah", and then zero or more occurrences of "pt".

If you want to do this for specific predicates **p** and **q**, that you can specify with IRI references, then it's just

```
?x p?/q* ?y
```

The ***** following the **q** means zero or more, and the **?** following the **p** means zero or one.

However, if you don't know the specific IRIs in advance, e.g., you want to use variables, in something like:

```
?x (?p)?/(?q)* ?y
```

then you may be out of luck.  SPARQL property paths don't support variables.  You can get *wildcards* in property paths with something like **s|!s**, since every URI is either **s** or it isn't, but there's no provision for putting repeatable variables into property paths.

Comment: I updated the description. Sorry if I am not describing it well. Basically there is a path that connects one of the IRIs to foo.com/f but I dont know how to connect a path from multiple directions